# Android Gradle javadoc annotation does not exists

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc

I'm trying to build an aar to publish on jcenter.

The assembleRelease task works ok, the javadoc task also works fine, but the javadocJar task outputs this error:

> /Users/martinmoreno/Projects/android-dev-utils/dev-utils/src/main/java/com/tinchoapps/devutils/BitmapUtils.java:11: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
>       import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

Here is the (simplified) gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'


android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
...
}

...

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

It seems related to the dependencies because it's giving some "class not found" exceptions too on classes inside the imports, but can't figure out what's wrong.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you use proguard in this case?

Comment: nop, I've editted with the proguard settings

Comment: I can see you already tried some solutions :) Is it compiling without errors if you remove annotations from `BitmapUtils`?

Comment: Have you tried compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0' ?

Comment: @gabriele the compile statement is there already

Answer (score 18):

This fixed various similar errors for me:

Add the following to build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    javadocDeps
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    javadocDeps 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:+'
}
```

In the JavaDoc Task add this line:

```
classpath += configurations.javadocDeps
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, but which `javadoc` task to put it in? Maven Install (via) plugin invokes `javadoc` instead of `androidJavadoc`.. And gradle doesn't allow me to modify the original `javadoc` task. Any ideas?

Comment: Create your own javadoc task like this:

task allJavadoc(dependsOn: ['assembleRelease'], type: Javadoc) {

    classpath += configurations.javadocDeps
}

Comment: How about just using this: `classpath += configurations.compile`

Comment: The answer from @louis-cad ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795272/234 ) also works, and is much simpler and easier

Answer (score 11):

Just add this line in your javadoc task (notice the last part: `+ configurations.compile`):

```
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator)) + configurations.compile
```

The last part of the line makes sure the javadoc use the compile dependencies to resolve the classes it's using for javadoc. At this point, it shouldn't fail anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Since the introduction of the `api` and `implementation` dependency configuration in [Android Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations), `compile` is deprecated. To include an `implementation` dependency in the javadoc classpath, I updated [Loius CADs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795272):

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator)) + configurations.implementation
}
```

I don't expect this to be the cleanest solution possible. There probably is a reason why `configuration.implementation` is not resolvable by default.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this while running `./gradlew install`. It was occurring when JavaDocs were being compiled (as far as I can understand).

I just added `failOnError false` to `task javadoc`.

```
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    failOnError false
}
```

What I understand is that we avoided failure on warnings that annotation library couldn't be found.

Comment: This worked for me. Getting error for support library and other dependant libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Following from Markus's answer, this is how I had to do it to make it work:

```
configurations {
    javadocDeps
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    javadocDeps 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'androidJavadocs') {
        task.configure {
            classpath += configurations.javadocDeps
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, instead of `androidJavadocs` I used `javadoc`.